# Can an SQL file be imported into Basic4Android?

Tags: android, sql, basic4android

I am trying to directly import an SQL file from a SQLite database into Basic4Android. I exported a .sql file and then I loaded the SQL file into the Basic4Android assets in the IDE.

Then I put this in my Process_Globals

```
Dim access As SQL
access.Initialize(File.DirAssets,"example.sql",True)
```

However the application crashes immediately on load when I try to run this code.

There's two things that I think could be wrong:

1. File.DirAssets is read-only and perhaps SQL can not be used from a read only directory. If that is the case then how else would I import an SQL file into the application.
2. Possibly the databases are incompatible but I would think they should be compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to export anything. Just copy the SQLite file to your project.

As you wrote it is not possible to open a database that is located in the assets folder. You should first copy it to a writable location.
[DBUtils](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/showthread.php?p=47359) can help you with this task.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this is not possible.

Open the .sql file in any text editor and you'll see it's a list of SQL statements.

An SQLite database file is an entirely different format as you'll see if you open it in a text editor.

Comment: Thanks. I've just had a closer look at the SQL file and it makes sense that you can't import the statements. There should be a method somehow though to export a file from SQLite that can be used in B4A.

Comment: If you have phpMyAdmin installed then you can export a MySQL database to various formats - not just .sql format.

CSV and XML are possible export formats - maybe they would be of use to you?